# What is double submit cookie? And how it is used in the prevention of CSRF attack?

Tags: web-application, csrf

I was looking at the CSRF prevention steps and was not able to understand how the double submit cookie works?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify at which point your question arises: Do you know how CSRF works? What resources did you consider? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Yes, I know how CSRF works. I am just not able to understand the concept of double submit cookie.

Comment: Have you read the [CSRF prevention cheat sheet section](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#user-content-double-submit-cookie) on it?